# Ruby on Rails: linking to a user-uploaded image in the layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, paperclip

The following is code to display each of a user's messages, along with the photo associated with each message. The code is located in a partial view from the home_controller.

```
<% msgs.each do |msg| %>
    <%- if msg.photo? -%>
         <%= image_tag msg.photo.url(:listsize) %>
    <%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

I can display the photo related to a particular message like this. The photo is uploaded by the user via paperclip in rails. The photo is stored in a column on the msg table in the database.

How can I display the latest photo uploaded by the user in the layout itself?

i.e something like `image_tag current_user.lastest.msg.photo.url(:listsize)` But again it needs to display in the layout, not in the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can, in fact, use:

```
 image_tag current_user.lastest.msg.photo.url(:listsize)
```

in your layout.  Obviously, you'll want to be careful with whether a user is or is not logged in.  Some code akin to:

```
 <%= image_tag current_user.lastest.msg.photo.url(:listsize) if current_user.present? %>
```

will work wonders.  Is there any other reason you're afraid to put this in the layout?

Comment: Just a small simplification of the above code:  <%= image_tag current_user.lastest.msg.photo.url(:listsize) if current_user.present? %>

Comment: Oddly, OP has reposted the question instead of editing on responding...  but thanks for the simplification